# Screen goes black after rotating the device only in ios 16

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios16

Some pages in the app support landscape mode.
After the ios 16 version was released
When turning the device horizontally, the screen becomes black, and only after turning horizontally again to the other side does the screen return to itself and the buttons function.
It is important to note that when I run on a device with iOS version 16 everything works great
I tried everything and could not find a solution
Has anyone tried this?

In my viewController:

```
    var orientationType : UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
        guard let parent = self.parent  else { return .allButUpsideDown }
        guard parent is BaseChannelViewController else { return .allButUpsideDown }
        
        return .portrait
    }
```

```
public func animate(fullscreenPresentation completionBlock : AnimationCompletion?)
    {
        guard displayMode != .fullscreen else { completionBlock?(); return }
        guard !isDisplayedModaly         else { completionBlock?(); return }
        
        switch transitionType
        {
        case .default    : fallthrough
        case .minimizable: fallthrough
        case .interactive:
            
            guard let transition   = customTransitioningDelegate as? GAVideoPlayerZoomTransition           else { break }
            guard let presentingVC = dataSource?.presentingViewController(for: self)                       else { break }
            let originFrame = dataSource?.initialFrameForTransitionToFullScreenDisplay(from: displayMode.initialScreenMode, for: self) ?? self.view.frame
            
            transition.currentFrame = originFrame
            
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .GAVideoPlayerViewControllerWillEnterFullscreen, object: self)
            
            hideControlsNoAnimation()
            
            if let _ = parent
            {
                removeFromParent()
            }
            
            // FIXME - Need this to prevent bad access crash, will show un balanced animation calls in the logger
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            
            let clientOrientationRawValue = clientOrientation.rawValue
            
            presentingVC.present(self, animated: true) { [weak self] in
                
                self?.displayMode = .fullscreen
                let currentOrientationRawValue = UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue
                UIDevice.current.setValue(clientOrientationRawValue, forKey: "orientation")
                UIDevice.current.setValue(currentOrientationRawValue, forKey: "orientation")
                
                completionBlock?()
            }
            break
            
        default: break
        }
    }
```

```
    fileprivate var clientOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation
    {
        return UIDeviceOrientation(interfaceOrientationMask: clientSupportedInterfaceOrientations)
    }
```

In AppDelegate:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
        guard let viewController = UIApplication.shared.topViewController() as? CustomOrientationViewController else { return .portrait }
        return viewController.orientationType
    }
```